# Javascript ajax only wakes up when adding a dummy line

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

I'm using an `onblur` event to pass on "this" (e.g. `this = input.password`). for some reason the
`handleServerResponse` does nothing unless I add a line to it, take a look:

Normal ajax function:

```
function ajaxFunction(obj) 
{
    var button = document.getElementById("submit");
    button.disabled = true;
    button.setAttribute("class", "test");
    var getdate = new Date();  //Used to prevent caching during ajax call
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse(obj);

    if(xmlhttp) 
    {
    //var input = document.forms["signup_form"].getElementsByTagName("input");
    xmlhttp.open("POST","register_ajax.php",true);

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    xmlhttp.send(obj.name +"="+ obj.value);
    };
}
```

handleServerResponse - Doesn't work

```
function handleServerResponse(obj) 
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
    {
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200) 
    {
            obj.value=xmlhttp.responseText; //Update the HTML Form element 
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("Error during AJAX call. Please try again");
    }
    }
}
```

handleServerResponse - Work's

```
function handleServerResponse(obj) 
{
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
    {
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200) 
    {
            obj.value=xmlhttp.responseText; //Update the HTML Form element 
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("Error during AJAX call. Please try again");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse(obj);
```

you are calling `handleServerResponse` rather than setting the on readystate change handler. You have to assign a function to `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` what you are doing is assigning the return of `handleServerResponse(obj)`. Try

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = function(){
                                  handleServerResponse(obj);
                              };
```

Also the reason why the second one succeeded is because the alert blocks execution an the ajax call finished before the checks were made.

Comment: Keep forgetting that javascript behaves different. Thanks, I can finally go to sleep.

Answer (score 3):

Your *"works"* accidentally works, it doesn't actually work.

What happens is:

1. xmlhttp request is sent (reply will come at a later time).
2. you immediately try check `readyState`, which is not `4` yet because isn't not ready yet!

In the other case this happens:

1. xmlhttp request is sent (reply will come at a later time).
2. You block the browser by using `alert`. While the alert is open the AJAX request returns.
3. You immediately check `readyState` and now it *is* `4`.

If you closed the `alert` *fast enough* it will break again.

The proper way to deal with AJAX (and asynchronousness in general) is to use event listeners.

```
xmlhttprequest.addEventListener("onreadystatechange", function (event) {
    if (xmlhttprequest.readyState === 4) {
        // handle reply
    }
});
```